# Symfony Twig config : how to exclude a folder from cached files

Tags: symfony, caching, path, configuration, twig

I have added a `path` entry in **Twig** config so I can also use template located in this folder:

```
twig:
    paths:
          '%kernel.project_dir%/modules': Modules
```

I would like to disable the cache **only for this path**, is this possible ?

If I do:

```
twig:
    cache: false
```

Then caching is disabled for *all templates*, even the default path (ie the files inside app/templates/...)

Another person will update these templates regularly and I want the app to take the changes into account without him having to call me to empty the Symfony cache (he has an ftp access to the template folder, but he has no access to the Symfony console to clear the cache)

Comment: Why do you want to exclude that specific folder from the twig cache?

Comment: @DarkBee because I want to allow a coworker to edit them and see the result without having to clear the Symfony cache (he does not have access to the console) (see my update)

Comment: There is an option `auto_reload` which you can set to true. I'd recommend putting this to `true` whilst developing. You could also trigger it with a `$_GET`

Comment: @DarkBee I will set this in prod environment (I accept the risk of app being down because of an error in html file). So `auto_reload` looks fine to me, thank you for this. Could you tell me a bit more about how `$_GET` could trigger a cache clear ?

Comment: Well you could set the option `auto_reload` to true when e.g. `$_GET['twig_reload'] == 1`

Comment: @DarkBee You mean something like creating a listener for all requests, and if `['twig_reload'] == 1` setting a new `Twig/Environment` instance with `auto_reload = true` ?